# Security patch 5994 (admin disclosure) not installed (magereport)

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-5994

I am install Security patch 5994 and it install successfully but in magereport they say Security patch 5994 (admin disclosure)  not installed

**applied.patches.list**

```
2016-12-09 05:49:57 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 259 (offset -14 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 152 with fuzz 2 (offset -10 lines).
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a core override? What site?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the patch related files extended in local folder, so that need to be updated as well as per new updated patch file.

That solved my issue in one of my project.

Hope that will help you, thanks